# Diffrence between component Extend attribute "task vs Group vs Scene vs filename" in BrightScript?

Tags: roku, brightscript

I used all four things in XML File But Not understand a difference anyone explains me.

Answer (score 0):

1. A "**Scene**" (or component extending the 'Scene') is a root of scene graph application. Rest of the components which you created are kept above the Scene.You can think 'roSGScreen' as a canvas for drawing and 'Scene' is first thing to be drawn. Thats why you should have atleast on Scene in every app.
2. "**Group**" is the base class of all renderable nodes like Label, Rectangle, Poster etc. If can control multiple renderable nodes defined in a Group. For example, if you have multiple labels and rectangles in a Group, you can control visibility of all nodes using group visibility.
3. To understand '**Task**', we need to understand scenegraph threading model. Every scene graph application has three threads available for developing application --

   **Main thread** -  this thread is launched from main.brs for all applications, and used to create Scene component object (which intern starts the next thread i.e. render thread or scene graph render thread)

   **Render thread** - this thread performs rendering of the scene graph components i.e. application visual elements

   **Task node thread** - these thread performs typical brightscript operations, by launching asynchronous threads.

**Why we need Task node thread** - some broghtscript operations can block the render thread and can lead to termination of the channel because of execution timeout. These operations can be performed using Task node thread.

Comment: what do you mean by  'filename'. I am unable to understand.

Comment: Sorry Its Render thread. Is It possible one application more than one Scene?

Comment: Hi Nikunj, yes its possible to have more then one scene. But everything can be manage by one scene only in an application. More than one scene will create unnecessary complications.

Comment: Thank you, Ok that's great. One more question. I write textbox, button and also use observefield to call function. I extend Group with this file. And I access this All File using another file extend with Scene. It's work using `m.keypanel = m.panelset.createChild("KeyboardDialogExample")` But Its not perform anykind of operation. Which I write in Function.

Comment: @NikunjChaklasiya I think you posted this question in another thread. I will check the code and let you know, if able to rectify the issue.

Comment: Ok, Thank you so much.